# Unable to scan WiFi network with 2 SSIDs

Tags: networking, debian, wifi

I am trying to scan WiFi networks and trying to connect to them using my Debian based NanoPi device. It is able to scan all the networks except for one.

This network has two SSIDs and both of them are on 2.4GHz band. They are on the same WiFi Channel.

So my laptop and mobile phone are able to scan these two networks.

But the NanoPi device is not scanning this network.

Is both the network on the same band and wifi channel causing interference with one another? Do I need to change the bands or the channel? Or something needs to be done at the device end? Why is my phone able to scan the network but the nano pi device is unable to scan?

Comment: Do both SSIDs send out beacon frames? If not you need to have active scanning (sending out probe request frames) on your NanoPi.    Which channel are those SSIDs on? Are you able to scan other SSIDs on that channel?

Comment: Yes both the SSIDs send out the beacon frames. But this is strange, today it is scanning the network. But some days it doesn't ??

Comment: One possible explanation could be that the SSIDs frequently change their channel number and your NanoPi is limited in the channels it scans due to the country settings. What channel are the SSIDs on when scanning works and when it doesn't work?

Comment: Yesterday it was able to scan the network and the channels were on Channel 1. Few days ago the channels were on 10, when the device was unable to scan.

Comment: Channel 10 is not subject to country restrictions, so that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Your two WiFi networks are definitely interfering with each other, changing the channel will solve this problem.
Since you are using 2.4 GHz band, I recommend you to use channels 1, 6, 11 (wide bandwidth) to avoid interference, though they aren't the very best for all cases, As for the optimal results use this [WiFi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=abdelrahman.wifianalyzerpremium) app, it will tell you the best channel to use for both networks.

Comment: This is definitely not the problem here. We are not talking about reduced throughput. OP is not seeing any beacon frames from the APs. Otherwise you would never be able to see more than one device on a single channel anywhere.